# DAOFactory and Service pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, web, dao

I just want to expand on this tutorial [Abstract DAO](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

I want to introduce UserService(interface) , JdbcUserService(Class) and similar services and their implementations.

1) Now Should I place a single DAOFactory instance in a place and use it from all these services or should I instantiate DAOFactory in each of these services. How to write tests for services' each methods.

2) How to remove hard coding like `DAOFactory.getInstance("javabase.jdbc");` and do this setup once across the application.

3) Also, from the web application perspective(multi-threading) what are the possible changes to do.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about why your service classes have implementations adapting to the database access strategies (jdbc). 
Are your services actually DAOs ? If not why not just making you services depending on interfaces rather than implementations ?

Comment: @yechabbi You are correct I got to make only one Service implementation. Now, Where to instantiate DAOFactory instance so that it is best shared among Services. A skeleton example of a plain JSP/Servlet application will answer all my questions.

Comment: I posted you a solution that is based on Inversion of Control (dependency injection) design principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making your classes resolving (internally, not through a constructor or a setter) their dependencies is generally a test-ability anti pattern. As an example, if you have that complex dependency for a class A and that you want to mock it for testing purposes, as the dependency itself is resolved by the class you won't be able to use a mock (unless you're modifying class A logic, which itself is another bad testing practice). Test-ability concerns are certainly one of the factors that have led to the wide spread of dependency injection popularity among developers.

If you use a dependency injection container (ex. Spring or jboss-weld...) your factory will be a bean managed by your container. You can define its scope as Singleton which corresponds to your need for sharing the same instance across your Service layer classes.

When testing, you can easily adjust your dependency container to provide you with a mock instance to ease your testing.

Comment: Actually I wanted to do it with plain web app. I've seen this design with Spring and trying to replicate in simple terms without DI.

Comment: I accept this as correct. Thanks for the help. However I would like to have a best design possible a with plain servlet / jsp application.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should probably use a common factory for making all your DB access classes, as they will be a "family" of related classes. Make an interface for the factory, then an implementation that uses DAOs to implement the classes. This way you could change the system to use some other way of storing data, or mock it for tests.
2. Use the factory class to hide this implementation detail. Also, you should not expose the raw DAO objects if at all possible. It's better to make a limited interface for stuff like "person" and "work function", that only exposes the methods you need, perhaps even at a higher level that DAO methods. Again, this allows you to hide details and change the implementation of the storage later (or for testing/mocking)
3. Add the sychronization to the classes that your factory generates. You will need to decide on amodel, but the simplest one is to start out by synchronizing all methods, and then later relaxing the locks if you need more performance.

Also: You might want to use the "Singleton" pattern to ensure that you only create one instance of your DAOFactory class.

So something like this..

Note that my "Singleton" does nothing to enforce the singleton principle. It's just intended to be used as the common way to get at the factory that is used at the moment.

```
interface Person {
  String getName();
  void setName();
}

interface PersonStorage {
  Collection<Person> getPersonsByName(final String name);
}

class DAOPerson implements Person {

  public synchronized String getName() {
    // Implementation here 
  }

  public synchronized void setName() {
    // Implementation here
  }

}

interface Factory {
  PersonFactory getPersonFactory();
}

class DAOPersonFactory implements PersonFactory {
  // Implementation
}

class DAOFactory implements Factory {

  PersonFactory getPersonFactory() {
    DAOPersonFactory res = new DAOPersonFactory();
    // Set up the instance, probably connect it to the underlying DAO
    return res;   
  }
}

class FactorySingleton {
  private Factory fac;

  FactorySingleton(final Factory implementation) {
    this.fac = implementation;
  }

  Factory getFactory() {
    return fac;
  }    

}
```